# Unable to install any overlay packages on FS39 with glibc depsolve errors

Tags: fedora, dependencies, glibc, amd

Fedora Silverblue 39

Trying to install and upgrade packages in `rpm-ostree` results in dependency errors with unresolvable `glibc` version conflicts.

I don't know if it may be related to [this issue](https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/fedora-silverblue-39-no-available-upgrade-despite-rpm-ostree-upgrade-preview-reports-available-updates/98446).

My system config:

- `$ uname -a`

```
Linux tsilvs-bravo15-001 6.6.3-200.fc39.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Nov 28 19:11:52 UTC 2023 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

- `# dmidecode -t system`

```
# dmidecode 3.5
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.2.0 present.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd.
    Product Name: Bravo 15 A4DDR
    Version: REV:1.0
    Serial Number: 9S716WK12030ZK6000010
    UUID: b340f1c4-cdef-d149-bb29-8d814d5bcaf9
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: 16WK.1
    Family: Br

Handle 0x0006, DMI type 12, 5 bytes
System Configuration Options
    Option 1: Default string

Handle 0x0007, DMI type 32, 20 bytes
System Boot Information
    Status: No errors detected
```

- `# dmidecode -t processor`

```
# dmidecode 3.5
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.2.0 present.

Handle 0x000F, DMI type 4, 48 bytes
Processor Information
    Socket Designation: FP6
    Type: Central Processor
    Family: Zen
    Manufacturer: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
    ID: 01 0F 86 00 FF FB 8B 17
    Signature: Family 23, Model 96, Stepping 1
    Flags:
        FPU (Floating-point unit on-chip)
        VME (Virtual mode extension)
        DE (Debugging extension)
        PSE (Page size extension)
        TSC (Time stamp counter)
        MSR (Model specific registers)
        PAE (Physical address extension)
        MCE (Machine check exception)
        CX8 (CMPXCHG8 instruction supported)
        APIC (On-chip APIC hardware supported)
        SEP (Fast system call)
        MTRR (Memory type range registers)
        PGE (Page global enable)
        MCA (Machine check architecture)
        CMOV (Conditional move instruction supported)
        PAT (Page attribute table)
        PSE-36 (36-bit page size extension)
        CLFSH (CLFLUSH instruction supported)
        MMX (MMX technology supported)
        FXSR (FXSAVE and FXSTOR instructions supported)
        SSE (Streaming SIMD extensions)
        SSE2 (Streaming SIMD extensions 2)
        HTT (Multi-threading)
    Version: AMD Ryzen 7 4800H with Radeon Graphics
    Voltage: 1.2 V
    External Clock: 100 MHz
    Max Speed: 4300 MHz
    Current Speed: 2900 MHz
    Status: Populated, Enabled
    Upgrade: None
    L1 Cache Handle: 0x000C
    L2 Cache Handle: 0x000D
    L3 Cache Handle: 0x000E
    Serial Number: Unknown
    Asset Tag: Unknown
    Part Number: Unknown
    Core Count: 8
    Core Enabled: 8
    Thread Count: 16
    Characteristics:
        64-bit capable
        Multi-Core
        Hardware Thread
        Execute Protection
        Enhanced Virtualization
        Power/Performance Control
```

Here's a few command logs:

- `$ rpm-ostree status`

```
State: idle
Deployments:
● fedora:fedora/39/x86_64/silverblue
                  Version: 39.20231204.0 (2023-12-04T00:53:36Z)
               BaseCommit: 91440dbfdf86c1c16838878da3f6765c52f4df22ebc6e0b679b5def113fbb99e
             GPGSignature: Valid signature by E8F23996F23218640CB44CBE75CF5AC418B8E74C
          LayeredPackages: alien android-tools autoconf automake beefy-miracle-backgrounds-gnome bison bottles breeze-cursor-theme breeze-icon-theme corectrl f38-backgrounds-extras-gnome fedora-jam-backgrounds-gnome flatseal flex gcc gdb
                           glibc-devel gnome-backgrounds-extras gnome-pomodoro gnome-tweaks godot heisenbug-backgrounds-extras-gnome heisenbug-backgrounds-gnome java-latest-openjdk laughlin-backgrounds-extras-gnome
                           laughlin-backgrounds-gnome libtool lovelock-backgrounds-gnome make menulibre neovim nodejs npm openssl patch qbittorrent qt5-qtquickcontrols remmina rpm-build rpmdevtools rpmlint screenkey seahorse subversion
                           vcmi verne-backgrounds-extras-gnome virt-manager vlc waydroid xmlstarlet yad zbar zenity
            LocalPackages: Blockbench-4.8.3-420.x86_64 gnome-media-keys-override-0.0.1-1.fc38.noarch ocs-url-3.0.3-1.fc20.x86_64 prospect-mail-0.5.2-1.x86_64 rpmfusion-free-release-39-1.noarch

  fedora:fedora/39/x86_64/silverblue
                  Version: 39.20231204.0 (2023-12-04T00:53:36Z)
               BaseCommit: 91440dbfdf86c1c16838878da3f6765c52f4df22ebc6e0b679b5def113fbb99e
             GPGSignature: Valid signature by E8F23996F23218640CB44CBE75CF5AC418B8E74C
          LayeredPackages: alien android-tools autoconf automake beefy-miracle-backgrounds-gnome bison bottles breeze-cursor-theme breeze-icon-theme corectrl f38-backgrounds-extras-gnome fedora-jam-backgrounds-gnome flatseal flex gcc gdb
                           glibc-devel gnome-backgrounds-extras gnome-pomodoro gnome-tweaks godot heisenbug-backgrounds-extras-gnome heisenbug-backgrounds-gnome java-latest-openjdk laughlin-backgrounds-extras-gnome
                           laughlin-backgrounds-gnome libtool lovelock-backgrounds-gnome make menulibre minetest neovim nodejs npm openssl patch qbittorrent qt5-qtquickcontrols remmina rpm-build rpmdevtools rpmlint screenkey seahorse
                           subversion vcmi verne-backgrounds-extras-gnome virt-manager vlc waydroid xmlstarlet yad zbar zenity
            LocalPackages: Blockbench-4.8.3-420.x86_64 gnome-media-keys-override-0.0.1-1.fc38.noarch ocs-url-3.0.3-1.fc20.x86_64 prospect-mail-0.5.2-1.x86_64 rpmfusion-free-release-39-1.noarch
```

- `$ rpm-ostree upgrade --check`

```
AvailableUpdate:
        Version: 39.20231215.1 (2023-12-15T18:09:18Z)
         Commit: 69c25b9951d821ba85a3fdca4ecf2afeb4317b28ce94d70034a23e31bbd97b3a
   GPGSignature: Valid signature by E8F23996F23218640CB44CBE75CF5AC418B8E74C
  SecAdvisories: 1 low, 6 moderate, 1 important
           Diff: 215 upgraded, 1 removed, 3 added
```

- `$ rpm-ostree upgrade` and `$ rpm-ostree install gstreamer1-plugins-{bad-\*,good-\*,base} gstreamer1-plugin-openh264 gstreamer1-libav --allow-inactive`

```
error: Could not depsolve transaction; 1 problem detected:
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - package bottles-1:51.9-5.fc39.noarch from updates requires glibc(x86-32), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package bottles-1:51.9-1.fc39.noarch from fedora requires glibc(x86-32), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package bottles-1:51.9-5.fc39.noarch from updates-archive requires glibc(x86-32), but none of the providers can be installed
  - glibc-2.38-14.fc39.i686 from updates  does not belong to a distupgrade repository
  - glibc-2.38-7.fc39.i686 from fedora  does not belong to a distupgrade repository
  - cannot install both glibc-2.38-14.fc39.x86_64 from updates and glibc-2.38-11.fc39.x86_64 from @System
  - cannot install both glibc-2.38-7.fc39.x86_64 from fedora and glibc-2.38-11.fc39.x86_64 from @System
  - cannot install both glibc-2.38-14.fc39.x86_64 from updates-archive and glibc-2.38-11.fc39.x86_64 from @System
```

- `$ rpm-ostree override replace ./glibc-2.38-14.fc39.x86_64.rpm`

```
error: Could not depsolve transaction; 2 problems detected:
 Problem 1: package glibc-all-langpacks-2.38-11.fc39.x86_64 from @System requires glibc = 2.38-11.fc39, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install both glibc-2.38-14.fc39.x86_64 from @commandline and glibc-2.38-11.fc39.x86_64 from @System
  - cannot install both glibc-2.38-14.fc39.x86_64 from @commandline and glibc-2.38-11.fc39.x86_64 from updates-archive
  - conflicting requests
 Problem 2: conflicting requests
  - package bottles-1:51.9-5.fc39.noarch from updates requires glibc(x86-32), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package bottles-1:51.9-1.fc39.noarch from fedora requires glibc(x86-32), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package bottles-1:51.9-5.fc39.noarch from updates-archive requires glibc(x86-32), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package glibc-2.38-14.fc39.i686 from updates requires glibc-common = 2.38-14.fc39, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package glibc-2.38-7.fc39.i686 from fedora requires glibc-common = 2.38-7.fc39, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install both glibc-common-2.38-14.fc39.x86_64 from updates and glibc-common-2.38-11.fc39.x86_64 from @System
  - cannot install both glibc-common-2.38-7.fc39.x86_64 from fedora and glibc-common-2.38-11.fc39.x86_64 from @System
  - cannot install both glibc-common-2.38-14.fc39.x86_64 from updates-archive and glibc-common-2.38-11.fc39.x86_64 from @System
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The depsolve conflict was due to `bottles` `.rpm` package dependenicy on older `glibc`.

Uninstalling the `bottles` `.rpm` package helped to solve it.

For now `bottles` is maintained and released officially by it's developers as a `flatpak`.